# Error "Could not find function" in 'caret' package, R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret, gbm

I am trying to run "gbm" via caret package in R. Receiving an '*method "gbm.fit" is not found*' error. gbm package is loaded, R, RStudio, caret and gbm are updated to their latest versions (see version info below)

Here is an [reproducible] example

loading required packages

```
library(caret)
library(gbm)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(magrittr)
library(plyr)
```

starting parallel (or not starting, the result is the same)

```
cl=makeCluster(5)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

Setting up control parameters for caret - pretty much all default

```
gbm.fit.control = trainControl(method = "cv", 
                               number = 5,
                               repeats = 1,
                               p = 0.75, 
                               verboseIter = T,
                               returnData = TRUE,
                               summaryFunction = defaultSummary
                               selectionFunction = "best",
                               allowParallel = FALSE)
```

Setting up grid for parameters search - nothing special

```
gbmGrid <-  expand.grid(interaction.depth = c(2,5,8),
                        n.trees = c(500,2000,5000),
                        shrinkage = c(0.1,0.01),
                        n.minobsinnode = c(10))
```

Generating dummy data for the example. Real data is more complex, but the result is the same with this toy example as well

```
tn.XY=data.frame(y=runif(100), x1=runif(100), x2=runif(100), x3=runif(100))
```

Attempting to run train function

```
gbmFit3 <- train(y~x1+x2+x3, data = tn.XY,
                 method = "gbm",
                 trControl = gbm.fit.control,
                 verbose = FALSE,
                 tuneGrid = gbmGrid,
                 ## Specify which metric to optimize
                 metric = "RMSE")
```

Getting the error = *gbm.fit is not found*

```
+ Fold1: shrinkage=0.01, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=5000 
model fit failed for Fold1: shrinkage=0.01, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=5000 
Error in do.call("gbm.fit", modArgs) : could not find function "gbm.fit"

- Fold1: shrinkage=0.01, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=5000 
+ Fold1: shrinkage=0.01, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=5000 
model fit failed for Fold1: shrinkage=0.01, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=5000 
Error in do.call("gbm.fit", modArgs) : could not find function "gbm.fit"
...
And it continues for every fold
```

I suspected that it could be an issue with parallel (like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029019/parallel-execution-of-train-in-caret-fails-with-function-not-found)) for example. However, disabling parallel execution did not help. I am kind of lost. I know some people used caret with a great success. It probably needs something basic, something I am missing.

R Version info

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plyr_1.8.3       magrittr_1.5     doParallel_1.0.8 iterators_1.0.7  foreach_1.4.2    gbm_2.1-06       survival_2.38-3 
 [8] caret_6.0-52     ggplot2_1.0.1    lattice_0.20-33  readr_0.1.1      installr_0.16.0
```

Comment: Now I have to decide how to deal with this - there were some fixes and features in the new version I liked ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. I thought that instead of deleting my question I will leave it here, maybe it'll help somebody. The problem was that I have installed new version from the github, which by some reason did not have gbm.fit method. So I have reinstalled it from the CRAN repository and the error went away.